# why is the content mode of a image view in collection the view is not changing to aspect fit ? . image are not shown as 200*200 cell size

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uiimageview

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PaYxp.png]    In collection view, I have changed content mode from storyboard in Xcode but image not in .
I am using a collection view in a view controller and in UIImage view I can't replace the aspect fill with aspect fit .

Comment: Can you please share a screenshot from setup in Storyboard and the end result when running the app? It would help us to try and identify what is the cause of such behavior.

Comment: Hi, can you add screenshot of what you have done in storyboard and what you want to achieve?

Comment: I am getting content mode of image view in collection view , as scaletofill mode but to see the image I need aspect fit.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

1. make sure all constraints are marked correct according to the cell.
2. in the Xcode inspector mark image content mode as aspect fit.
3. give image a height.